# rails form helper empty validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am new to rails and have the following rails form, which works fine.

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>'first name' %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>'last name' %>
<%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder=>'email address' %>
<%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder=>'password' %>
<%= f.password_field :password2, :placeholder=>'password2' %>
</p>
<%= f.submit 'Sign up!', :class=>'btn-custom btn-submit' %>
<% end %>
```

On the email textbox there is some client side validation built into it which will not submit the form and highlight the field if it detects a string that isn't the format of an  email address.

For some reason the built in form validation doesn't check whether the text fields are empty. Is there a rails way to make it check that?

I understand that I could do it with jquery and will do it that way if there is no other way but it seems silly to have 2 separate forms of validation code.

fyi I also have validation on my model.

Comment: "it seems silly to have 2 separate forms of validation code" - do you mean in your jQuery? I don't see what the problem is, if you already have a JS function validating the email field then extending it to validate the other fiels should be fairly simple. Can you post your jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :pattern => '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',  :placeholder=>'email address' %>
```

Moreover:

you have these:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>'first name' %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder=>'last name' %>
```

I guess it should be

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder=>'first name' %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder=>'last name' %>
```

Comment: Yeah good spotting fixed up the email thing and the :required => true works a treat! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why have you got `:email` on every line here?

```
<%= f.text_field  :email, :placeholder=>'first name' %>
                  ^^^^^^ Here
<%= f.text_field  :email, :placeholder=>'last name' %>
                  ^^^^^^^ and here 
<%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder=>'email address' %>
```

Shouldn't they be called `:firstname` and `:lastname`? (or whatever the attributes are called in your model.)

I'm not sure what kind of validation you're talking about. If you mean client-side validation, i.e. to prevent the form from submitting at all if there are blank fields, this has to be done through Javascript. Rails is server-side code so can't do anything with the form data until it's already been submitted.

To validate the fields server side you'd just add something like this in your model:

```
validates :email,     presence: true
validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :lastname,  presence: true
```

... which you say you've already done, but I'm including this for full reference for anyone who might be reading this question in the future.